# Airflow Kubernetes Pod Operator exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to use Kubernetes Pod Operator to create a pod using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

COPY test_script.py /opt/test_script.py
RUN chmod +x /opt/test_script.py

RUN pip install boto3
RUN pip install pandas
```

And all I want the pod to do is run the test_script.py. The Kubernetes Pod Operator in my DAG looks like:

```
k_op = KubernetesPodOperator(
            task_id='TASK_ID',
            name='TASK_ID',
            namespace='nmspc',
            resources={'request_memory': "1G", 'request_cpu': 1},
            image='<docker_image_location>',
            image_pull_policy='Always',
            cmd = ['python'],
            arguments=['/opt/test_script.py'],
            dag=dag,
            labels={'dag_id': 'TASK_ID'})
```

When I run the DAG and check the eks pod that the image is building and running on, I get this error:

`standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"`

And I can't figure out why. I thought chmod +x on the script would work but it did not as according to other answers I've seen.

Comment: Does it work if you change your Dockerfile to set `CMD ["/opt/test_script.py"]`, and leave out the `cmd=` and `arguments=` options?  What sort of system did you use to build and push the image?

Comment: It doesn't work if I remove the kubernetes pod operators and use CMD in the Dockerfile. I built the docker image on my local machine and pushed to AWS ECS.

Comment: If you built it locally, does `docker run $docker_image_location python /opt/test_script.py` work for you? and are you _sure_ you've included the whole `Dockerfile` in your question here?

Comment: Yes the whole Dockerfile is present here. I tried running it locally. I don't get any output but I also don't get any errors.